# UIPicker and Keyboard conflict

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uipickerview

what i have is 3 textFields and whenever i touch textField1 or textField2 Picker changes values and there is no keyboard. When i touch textField3 keyboard appears and the picker goes hidden.Now if i dismiss the keyboard by clicking return and then click textField1 picker appears again, but if i dont dismiss the keyboard BY CLICKING BUTTON it stays over the picker. What I need is when the keyboard is firstResponder (and i see it on the screen) to hide it if i click on the textField1 and only to see the picker

```
int variabla;

    -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        [pickerView setHidden:YES];
        if (textField1.editing == YES) {
            [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
            [pickerView setHidden:NO];
            variabla = 1;
        }else if (textField2.editing == YES) {  
            [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
            [pickerView setHidden:NO];
            variabla = 2;
        }   
        NSLog(@"variabla %d",variabla); 
        [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
    {
        return 1;
    }
    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {
        if (variabla == 1) {
            return [pickerArray1 count];
        }else if (variabla == 2) {
            return [pickerArray2 count];
        }else {
            return 0;
        }   
    }
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {   
        if (variabla == 1) {
            return [pickerArray1 objectAtIndex:row];        
        }else if (variabla == 2) {
            return [pickerArray2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }else {
            return 0;
        }   
    }
    - (void)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{ 
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [pickerView setHidden:YES];
    pickerArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", nil];
    pickerArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok for solve this problem you can use lot of option i tell you one of them.

```
- (void)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

  if([textField isEqual:yourTextField3])
  {
    yourPicker.hidden=YES;
  }
  else
  {

    [yourTextField3 resignFirstResponder];
    [self performSelector:@selector(textFieldFirstResponderOnDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
  }
}


- (void)textFieldFirstResponderOnDelay {
  yourPicker.hidden=NO;
}
```

And whatever you want you can put in to these conditions.

or you can add tag with your textfield and check accordingly.Hide picker whenever you want or display picker and hide keyboard whenever you want.

Comment: @spire this definately works but its on you how you are using this according to you.and this is answered by Ishu

Comment: Bro, you missing some where ok give the portion of code to check the mistake it definately works i use this a number of time.

Comment: use edited one(change TextField to textField.may this help you.

Comment: Sorry for the name here is the code --- -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 
 if([textField isEqual:textField3])
 {
  pickerView.hidden=YES;
 }
 else
 {
  pickerView.hidden=NO;
  [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
  if (textField1.editing == YES) {   
   variabla = 1;
  }else if (textField2.editing == YES) {   
   variabla = 2;
  }
  NSLog(@"variabla %d",variabla); 
  [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
 } 
}

Comment: You've also missed the square brackets there but that's not the point, i know what you meant i will put all the code in the answer so you can see it

Comment: Humm i edit that one also.Check OnDelay.This type of problem i also face on iPhone 4.0 or above.

Comment: Also change DidBegainEditing to shouldBegainEditing

Comment: did some modification but...almost perfect now i only  need to pres twice on textField3 so the keyboard can appear first time the Picker id hiding and the second time the keyboard appears.Also i need first to click on textField1 or 2 only then i can click on textField3

Comment: you want to disable textField3 editing untill press occurs on textField1 or 2 right. For this you disable textField3 in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad then else block (in above code) enable your textField3.

Comment: No you misunderstand me, textField3 is disabled with the code you have provided and I want to enable it.With your code First Responder must be initialized with textField1 or textField2 so that textField3 can call the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
  @implementation UIPickerViewController
    int variabla;
    -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

        if([textField isEqual:textField3])
        {
            pickerView.hidden=YES;
        }
        else
        {
            pickerView.hidden=NO;
            [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
            if (textField1.editing == YES) {            
                variabla = 1;
            }else if (textField2.editing == YES) {          
                variabla = 2;
            }
            NSLog(@"variabla %d",variabla); 
            [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
        }   
    }

    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
    {
        return 1;
    }
    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {
        if (variabla == 1) {
            return [pickerArray1 count];
        }else if (variabla == 2) {
            return [pickerArray2 count];
        }else {
            return 0;
        }   
    }
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {   
        if (variabla == 1) {
            return [pickerArray1 objectAtIndex:row];        
        }else if (variabla == 2) {
            return [pickerArray2 objectAtIndex:row];
        }else {
            return 0;
        }   
    }
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField
*)textField{    
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [pickerView setHidden:YES];
        pickerArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", nil];
        pickerArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
    }
```

and the .h file

```
@interface UIPickerViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {

    IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField3;
    NSArray *pickerArray1;
    NSArray *pickerArray2;
    UIButton *hideKeyboardButton;

}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
@end
```

Comment: use textFieldShouldBeginEditing  instead of textFieldDidBeginEditing.

Comment: But then textField3 cannot become first responder and no keyboard is showing when i click it. I have to click it twice so the keyboard can appear

Answer (score 0):

Got it THX for your help

```
-(void)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    pickerView.hidden=YES;
    if ([textField isEqual:textField3]) {

    }
    else if([textField isEqual:textField1])
    {
        [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
        [self performSelector:@selector(textFieldFirstResponderOnDelay1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }else {
        [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
        [self performSelector:@selector(textFieldFirstResponderOnDelay2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}

-(void)textFieldFirstResponderOnDelay1{ 
    pickerView.hidden=NO;
    variabla = 1;

    NSLog(@"variabla %d",variabla); 
    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
-(void)textFieldFirstResponderOnDelay2{ 

    pickerView.hidden=NO;
    variabla = 2;

    NSLog(@"variabla %d",variabla); 
    [pickerView reloadAllComponents];
}
```

picker must be initialized before touching textField3